# Get hash values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I take only the values of multiple keys from a hash without specifying the key?
This is my hash:

```
{Sat, 23 Nov 2013=>12, Fri, 22 Nov 2013=>15, Thu, 21 Nov 2013=>13}
```

Comment: Please update your question with a valid hash (e.g. one that you can enter into irb) and with clarified question (e.g. example of the output you are seeking)

Comment: What do you mean with "values of multiple keys"? Are you trying to get all the values or just a subset?

Comment: I just wanted to compare the values, but I need to modify my code, to return a valid hash. And thank you all for the help.

Comment: @marzapower: How would you care to represent dates in this hash?  That's what you're quibbling about -- how dates are represented.  If you understand the way that the system (irb) is representing dates then it's a perfectly valid hash -- there is a single unique object as a key with a single object as a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So because I just needed the values of the keys from that hash(or not, how cares)

```
h = {Sat, 23 Nov 2013=>12, Fri, 22 Nov 2013=>15, Thu, 21 Nov 2013=>13}
h.each_value {|v| t << v}
t => [12, 15, 13]
```

Answer (score 6):

with **hash#values**:

```
a = {"Sat, 23 Nov 2013"=>12, "Fri, 22 Nov 2013"=>15, "Thu, 21 Nov 2013"=>13}
a.values
```

result:

```
[12, 15, 13]
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you only wanted your even values and wanted to assign them to an array like so ... use the .even_value method on your hash:

```
hash = {"Sat, 23 Nov 2013"=>12, "Fri, 22 Nov 2013"=>15, "Thu, 21 Nov 2013"=>13} 
array = []
hash.each_value {|i| array << i if i.even? }
puts array # [12]
```

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-each_value

.even_value only looks at the values and allows you to do select style options on it or whatever you need!

Answer (score 0):

It's not 100% clear what you're asking, but if you're looking to use some kind of predicate by which to select values, you want to use #select.

```
hash = {"Sat, 23 Nov 2013"=>12, "Fri, 22 Nov 2013"=>15, "Thu, 21 Nov 2013"=>13} 
results = hash.each_value.select { |v| ... }
```

Where the `...` is the condition you want to specify. Could be something like `v.even?` or `v.odd?` or `v % 3 == 0` any other boolean.